# DataTable Processing Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm working on loading a new datatable when the user clicks on a button. The new datatable is populated by a server side script. When the user clicks on the button the datatable hangs and says "Processing".

```
$('#QuerySelectedBtn').on('click', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{ 
             url: './datasource02.php',
             type: 'get',
                error: function(){  // error handling
                  $(".example-error").html("");
                  $("#example").append('<tbody class="example-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                  $("#example_processing").css("display","none");
                  }
              },
              "columns": [
              { "data": "ID" },
              { "data": "user_id" },
              { "data": "option_name" },
              { "data": "option_value" }
              ],
              "order": [],
              "dom": 'lfrtipB',        
              "buttons": {
                 "dom": {
                    "button": {
                      "tag": "button",
                      "className": "btn"
                     }
                   },
                   "buttons": [ 
                        { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copy' },
                        { extend: 'csv', text: 'CSV' },
                        { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' }, 
                        { extend: 'pdf', text: 'PDF' }, 
                        { extend: 'print', text: 'Print' } 

                    ]   
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does datasource02.php return?

Comment: Maybe your browser devloper consoles displayed any errors. let me know those errors.

Comment: This is the error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution  :** Instead of using this line `$("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();` use below code

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 table.destroy();
```

**Reason :**

```
1.   $("#example").dataTable();` // .fnDestroy() works

2 . $("#example"). DataTable();' // .fnDestroy() doesn't work  
                                   //.destroy();  will work
```

**Problem in your current configuration :**

Your using  this API :  `dataTable().fnDestroy();` this will not work with `DataTable();` api

For reference : https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: Thanks for this information! This alone didn't solve the problem though. I discovered that the problem has to do with the number of rows in the datatable. The initial datatable that I load has three cols and the second datatable I load has four cols. After adding a four col in the HTML using <th> the second table loads. I need to figure out how to hide/show this col.

Comment: I was able to add the column definitions in the Jquery code that calls the server-side data source. I removed the cols from the HTML and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good Enjoy the coding @MikeG